# React- Render two different data arrays in a single card

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have fetched card images and data into a object. But I am not to render image and data object. Please find below my rough implementation,

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import {Row, Col, Card} from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Container} from 'react-bootstrap';

export const App = () => {

  const [ users, getUsers ] = useState([]);

  const getUsersData = useCallback(async () => {
    const [image, userData] = await Promise.all([
      axios.get('https://...'),
      axios.get('https://...')
    ]);
    getUsers({ image: image.data, data: userData.data});
  },[])

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsersData()
  },[getUsersData]);

  return (
    <>
    <Container>
      <h1>User Details</h1>
      <Row>
          {/* {
            users?.image?.map(user => (
              <Card.Img src={user?.image} variant='top' />
            ))
          } */}
          {
            users?.data?.map(user => (
             <Col sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
              <Card className='my-3 p-3 rounded'>
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>
                    <strong>{user?.name}</strong>
                  </Card.Title>
                  <Card.Text as='h3'>{user?.details}</Card.Text>
                </Card.Body>
               </Card>
              </Col>
             ))
          }
      </Row>
    </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

[Users Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RMnm.png)

How can I add image card in data card?

here image and data object needs to be mapped in same card. and size of image and data array is different so cannot combine objects into single object

Comment: When you do that, do you see just one image or you do not see any image?

Comment: @Evren no image as mapping is not correct

Comment: @Evren I have edited code now

Answer (score 0):

I think your `users` state structure is not clear with your question but if it has structured like you share, this solution should work. Otherwise I would recommend you to add how `users` state looks like to your question

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import {Row, Col, Card} from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Container} from 'react-bootstrap';

export const App = () => {

  const [ users, getUsers ] = useState([]);

  const getUsersData = useCallback(async () => {
    const [image, userData] = await Promise.all([
      axios.get('https://...'),
      axios.get('https://...')
    ]);
    getUsers({ image: image.data, data: userData.data});
  },[])

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsersData()
  },[getUsersData]);

  return (
    <>
    <Container>
      <h1>User Details</h1>
      <Row> 
          {
            users?.map(user => (
             <Col sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
              <Card className='my-3 p-3 rounded'>
              <Card.Img src={user?.image?.image} variant='top' />
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>
                    <strong>{user?.data?.name}</strong>
                  </Card.Title>
                  <Card.Text as='h3'>{user?.data?.details}</Card.Text>
                </Card.Body>
               </Card>
              </Col>
             ))
          }
      </Row>
    </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I have added snap of Users object. It has data and image arrays, so cannot map directly.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized the state with an empty array. It means that the state can take only the array value. That's ok. But at the time of setting it, you are setting an object to the state. You must either initialize the state with a null value or update the state with the previous state value. I'll go with initializing the state with a null value.

```
const [ users, getUsers ] = useState(null);
```

Your return React element would be like this

```
<Container>
  <h1>User Details</h1>
  <Row>
     {users && users.data.map((user) => ( //update
      <Col sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
        <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded">
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>
              <strong>{user.name}</strong>
            </Card.Title>
            <Card.Text as="h3">{user.details}</Card.Text>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    ))}
  </Row>
</Container>
```